# Проблема с Firefox'ом и свойством line-height

Tags: html, css

[image]

Привет, в самом начале отчищаю стили при помощи clear.css, там есть такое правило:

```
body{ line-height: 1em; }
```

Что оно делает? С ним, в firefox, inline-block объекты отображаются по разному, например такие (пик сверху):

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #7B1D44;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

текст на кнопке в файрфокс заметно ниже чем в других браузерах, в старой опере тоже чуть ниже но это без разницы, а вот файрфокс никуда не годится. Я бы убрал это свойство и переверстал с другими паддингами, но оно есть во всех популярных clear и значит, как бы, нужно.

Может быть кто сталкивался с этим, посоветуйте как быть....

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/VxYRt/3/

Comment: Вроде решилось вариантом указывания для таких элементов: `line-height: normal`, но всё равно, может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство lihe-height задаётся для расчета высоты одной строки. Когда вы указываете для body  line-height равный 1em, то этим вы сообщаете браузеру, что высота одной строчки будет равна высоте размера по умолчанию. Если я не ошибаюсь, то он равен 16px. В кнопке вы ставите размер шрифта 18px и текст начинает опускаться вниз ( вылезать за пределы высоты строчки ), размер строчки наглядно демонстрируется фоном.

line-height: normal это значение по умолчанию, которое заставляет браузер автоматически пересчитывать высоту строки ( в том числе в зависимости и от указанного font-size). Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Да, более чем понятно, спасибо. Единственное так ли важно это правило для `очищения стилей` (clear.css)?

Comment: Мне трудно сказать. Как правило, во многих css фреймворках с документацией обычно расписывается почему то или иное правило было добавлено. Советую вам обратиться к документации одного из них и найти ответ на свой вопрос.